# Can I pass Particular Values from html page to My Activity?

Tags: android

I have one query. Can I pass Value from my html page to My Activity file.

html file located in assets/www folder and Activity file located in src/package_name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use JavaScriptInterface. In your web view add this Interface.

1. Make JavaScriptInterface class like (Here you can use any name for your class)

   ```
    public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        JavaScriptInterface(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        /** Get passed value from the web page here */
        public void showMyValue(String passedValue) {
            android.util.Log.i("TAG", "I Got this value:" + passedValue);
        }
    }
   ```
2. Add this interface in your webview like

   ```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
   ```
3. Now in your webpage, call this method to pass your value and do something need full with that value

   ```
    <input type="button" value="ClickMe" onClick="passValueToAndroid('Hello Android!')" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function passValueToAndroid(yourPassingValue) {
         Android.showMyValue(yourPassingValue);
     }
    </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass any variable from html to activity.

You need to create JavaScript Interface to interact between html to activity,

Refer this link for implementation detail

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: I am not getting exact solution. can you put small example. Please.